# The way around using rpc/encoded style in CXF

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I know that CXF does not support the rpc/encoded WSDL style and I am looking for a solution to get the way around this. I have to do the implementation of rpc/encoded style web service, the problem is that the service has to be deployed in Apache Karaf 2.2.9 as an OSGi bundle which uses CXF 2.6.2 and there is no way I can implement the rpc/encoded ws.

What I am thinking is to create another web service, which will be running on a different container and would be generated with Axis 1.4. It would work as a wrapper for CXF web service which is deployed into Karaf.

I don't really like this solution, because there has to be another container involved. Maybe someone can suggest me the solution how to make this work without other container? (If it is possible at least).

Comment: RPC/encoded? You sure seem to believe in making things hard for yourself…

Comment: It is not my self I want to make things harder, I definitely don't want that :) that is the client who is using ancient rpc/encoded services and can't do anything to change this.

Comment: why do you need one web service to wrap the other. Why not put them on different URLs altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glen has a tutorial for that:

http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/calling_rpc_encoded_web_services

but it really isn't that straight forward.

Comment: link is obsolete, I think the correct one is this. https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/calling-rpc-encoded-web-services